# Alter Table From Cassandra to Elasticsearch SYNC - Elassandra

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra

I have created a table via elasticsearch and was sync to cassandra:

```
 _id | message                                    | postDate                            | user
-----+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------
   2 |     ['Another tweet, will it be indexed?'] | ['2009-11-15 14:12:12.000000+0000'] | ['kimchy']
   1 | ['Trying out Elassandra, so far so good?'] | ['2009-11-15 13:12:00.000000+0000'] | ['kimchy']
```

**when I altered the table tweet and add email column:**

> ALTER TABLE tweet ADD email varchar;

```

```
 _id | email | message                                    | postDate                            | user
-----+-------+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------
   2 |  null |     ['Another tweet, will it be indexed?'] | ['2009-11-15 14:12:12.000000+0000'] | ['kimchy']
   1 |  null | ['Trying out Elassandra, so far so good?'] | ['2009-11-15 13:12:00.000000+0000'] | ['kimchy']
```

```
The email has been added but and appears **null**.

But when I query on elasticsearch It doesn't sync:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "twitter",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"postDate":"2009-11-15T14:12:12.000Z","message":"Another tweet, will it be indexed?","user":"kimchy"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "twitter",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"postDate":"2009-11-15T13:12:00.000Z","message":"Trying out Elassandra, so far so good?","user":"kimchy"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

**The question is how am I be able to sync the changes of the table from cassandra to elasticsearch?**

Comment: what are you using to sync the data..

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I answer in case someone find it.

In Elassandra, when you create a cassandra table or column, it is not automatically indexed by elastisearch. You need either create or update the mapping :

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/twitter/" -d '{
   "settings" : { "keyspace" : "twitter" } },
   "mappings" : {
      "tweet" : {
            "properties" : {
              "email" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Now the elasticsearch index contains a new `email` field. Any new email inserted with CQL will be indexed automatically and available for search within a second.

But it's important to note that email entries added before the mapping update will not be searchable yet. It is necessary to use nodetool to rebuild the index with old data included:

```
nodetool flush tweeter
nodetool rebuild_index --threads 4 tweeter tweet elastic_tweet_idx
```